# How can I add buttons to a textarea in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Thank you for taking a look at my question!

What I'm trying to do in bootstrap is add a textarea that have text-editor buttons in them.. "bold", "italic" and "attachment" it's supposed to look like this:

[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1tq4.png)

But instead I have this:

[My Results so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPXfZ.png)

The main problems I'm having is:

- Hot to Prevent text in textarea from going under the editor buttons
- What do I need to override in buttons to get the desired effects

By the way I'm using a bootstrap template/theme its called remark, I'm using one of their editor element:

getbootstrapadmin.com/remark/base/forms/editor-markdown.html

template/11989202

HTML I have so far:

```
<div>

     <div class="md-header btn-toolbar btn-toolbar-btm">
       <div class="btn-group">

       <button class="btn-default btn-sm btn btn-pure" type="button" title="Bold" tabindex="-1" data-provider="bootstrap-markdown" 
       data-handler="bootstrap-markdown-cmdBold" data-hotkey="Ctrl+B"><span class="fa fa-bold">
       </span> </button>

       <button class="btn-default btn-sm btn btn-pure" type="button" title="Italic"
       tabindex="-1" data-provider="bootstrap-markdown" data-handler="bootstrap-markdown-cmdItalic" 
       data-hotkey="Ctrl+I"><span class="fa fa-italic"></span> </button>

       <button class="btn-default btn-sm btn btn-pure" type="button" title="Heading" tabindex="-1">
       <span class="icon wb-attach-file"></span> </button>
       </div>
      </div>

      <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Type something here..."></textarea>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .btn-toolbar-btm{
  position:absolute;
  top:212px;
  margin-left:8px;
  z-index:3;
    }
```

If you can help me in any way I will GREATLY appreciate it, you would literally save my job :/

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
<div class="form-group required-field-block">       
        <div class="col-md-12 input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span>
            <textarea rows="3" size="30" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Sporočilo"></textarea>  
                <div class="required-icon">
                    <div class="text">*</div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```